# How to specify multiple exclusion filters in --gtest_filter?

Tags: googletest

The question is about google-test framework.
I want to run all tests excluding some according to multiple exclusion filters, like:
`--gtest_filter=-ABC.*:-BCD.*`

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You group the patterns in the form `--gtest_filter=POSTIVE_PATTERNS[-NEGATIVE_PATTERNS]`

So in this case, you want `--gtest_filter=-ABC.*:BCD.*`

Comment: Great. It took me a while what the grouping meant and the exact difference between the example of the OP and the answer. Notice the '-' character is a single character that affects both expressions. The op on the other hand adds the '-' character to each expression.

Comment: But a bit of explanation that I need a SINGLE '-' character before all negative patterns instead of adding it to each filter would be nice. I had to read the answer 3 times to understand that it is indeed a correct answer (and actually a @PauloNeves 's comment helped)

Answer (score 37):

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taxiahou/2013/07/30/the-usage-of-running-a-subset-of-tests-in-google-test-framework-gtest_filter/. You can find a clear example there.

Exclusions are identified by '-' sign. You can say multiple seperated by :. no need of repeating - with :.

`--gtest_filter=-*str*` :This will run tests that don't contain string "str".

`--gtest_filter=-*str1*:*str2*` :This will run tests that don't contain either "str1" or "str2":

`--gtest_filter=*str*:-*str1*:*str2*` :This will run tests that contain str and that do not contain either str1 or str2.

So, anything followed by '-' will be counted for exclusion list.

So, in your case it will be `--gtest_filter=-ABC.*:BCD.*`